# Kickstart partitioning help

Tags: centos, raid, partition, kickstart

I need to configure a RAID using a kickstart file. I have four hardrives sda sdb sdc and sdd on which I plan to set-up the following partitions:

- hda1 and hdb1 I want them to be set as a 8GB primary partition, ext3, formated,
- hda2 and hdb2 a 4GB primary partition, ext3, formated,
- hda3 and hdb3 to fill the rest of the remaing space, primary partition, ext3, formated,
- hdc1 and hdd1 set each one as a primary partion, ext3 and formated.

I want to build a software RAID1 using:
- hda1 and hdb1 mounted as /, 
- hda2 and hdb2 mounted as swap,
- hda3 and hdb3 mounted as /sp,
- hdc1 and hdd1 mounted as /sp2.

Can someone help me configure that in a kickstart file? I'm using a kickstart configurator from CentOS 5.5 and can't seem to find a way to configure that using this GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it's not very effectual to put partitions of the same hard disk into different raid groups. You might be better served by putting hda and hdb into a LVM and then carving out logical volumes from there.

The relevant commands in your kickstart would be like this:

**

part raid.01 --ondisk=hda --asprimary --size=8000

part raid.02 --ondisk=hdb --asprimary --size=8000

raid / --fstype=ext3 --level=1 --device=md0 raid.01 raid.02

**

It's the same for all the rest, adjusting drives, size and filesystems as needed.

Comment: I'm also using /usr/bin/yum update -y just after the %post section and I always get this error message: Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
[Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution')>